getting 404 not found error when nesting routes in express js
I'm working on rest api for my application and I have problem with nesting routes in express. I have nested routes and when I try to send request to nested url express sends back 404 not found.
index for all api routes (src/routes/index.ts):
import { Router } from 'express';

import accountRouter from './accounts.js';
import cashflowRouter from './cashflows.js';

const api = () => {
  const router = Router();

  // cashflows <- 404
  router.use('/accounts/:account-id/cashflows', cashflowRouter());

  // accounts <- this works well
  router.use('/accounts', accountRouter());

  return router;
}

export default api;

cashflow router (src/routes/cashflows.ts)
import { Router } from 'express';

import cashflows from '../controllers/cashflows.js';

const api = () => {
  const router = Router();

  // GET /accounts/:account-id/cashflows <- get all cashflows
  router.get('/', cashflows.find);

  // GET /accounts/:account-id/cashflows/:id <- get one cashflow
  router.get('/:id', cashflows.findOne);

  // POST /accounts/:account-id/cashflows <- add cashflow
  router.post('/', cashflows.add);

  // PATCH /accounts/:account-id/cashflows/:id <- get all cashflows
  router.patch('/:id', cashflows.update);

  // DELETE /accounts/:account-id/cashflows/:id <- get all cashflows
  router.delete('/:id', cashflows.remove);

  return router;
}

export default api;

I've been searching for a solution, but I can't find one.
Strange thing is that when I send request to nested url with account-id param empty I don't get 404 error. My express version: ^4.19.2
I tried using cashflowRouter as middleware for accountRouter and set mergeParams property of casflowRouter to true (It didn't work). I also tried defining nested route directly in index.ts file (not what I want) and It worked.
Here's code I tried:
router.get('/accounts/:id/example', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.params.id);
  })

that route was above all other routes.

What does an example request look like? URL wise. Also share the app where all Routers eventually get hooked up to.

Responding to request of Chuckwujiobi Canon:
index.ts file:


import http from 'node:http';

import express from 'express';
import { expressjwt, Params } from 'express-jwt';

import database from './config/database.js';
import getPublicKey from './utils/getPublicKey.js';

import apiRouter from './routes/index.js';

const {
  PORT,
  ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  BASE_URL,
} = process.env;

const publicKey = getPublicKey();
const authConfig: Params = {
  secret: publicKey,
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
  issuer: ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  audience: BASE_URL,
}

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));

app.get('/api/v1', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to expens rest api v1!',
  });
});

app.use('/api/v1', expressjwt(authConfig), apiRouter());

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server up on localhost:${PORT}!`);
});

const gracefulShutdown = () => {
  server.close(async () => {
    await database.end();
    console.log('closed connection to database!');
    server.closeAllConnections();
    console.log('closed all connections!');
    process.exit(0);
  });
}

process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGUSR2', gracefulShutdown);



one of requests that resulted in 404:
postman screenshot
rest-api-host is localhost

Can cashflows.find() throw a possible 404?

It can't and even if it could, error message would be diffrent
